# How to copy void * memory from cgo to a slice

Tags: go

Go program invoked a C library and get a memory presented as a `void *` and its `size`.

Now I need to copy that memory to a slice, how to do so?

```golang
func recvData(data unsafe.Pointer, size C.size_t) []byte {
    s := make([]byte, size, size)

    // now copy data into s

    return s
}
```

I know that thru reflection, I can call `C.memcpy` to copy `data` to `s.Data`, but it seems to be inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You mean `C.GoBytes`?

Comment: What a Go beginner I am.